# Lucene-Core disk usage

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am experiencing a bit of an issue with Lucene-Core in my Java application... I have configured a directory for Lucene to store its segments in and I monitor the directory's size. As it stands Lucene seems to be consuming any and all free space on the drive in a constant upward trend.

Is this to be expected? Have I just not given it enough space to level out? I was under the impression that merging should happen which would clear out any duplicate/delete indexes, however, I never see a dip in consumption.

I have read a number of articles explaining that Lucene simply marks indexes as deleted but doesn't actually free up disk space until a merge occurs and that the use of Optimize/ForceMerge is frowned upon.

Does anyone have any recommendations/similar experiences with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently using Lucene-Core 3.6.

Sam

Comment: Are you deleting documenting from the the lucene index? because you are expecting it to reduce in the size. Regarding the space consumed by the indexes, what type of data are you indexing and how are you tokenizing it because more the number of tokens, more space will be consumed.

Comment: Hey YoungHobbit,

Thank you for replying.

I am basically indexing information on an object linked via a unique id.

Before doing an IndexeWriter.addDocument, I do a deleteDocument with a query term matching the unique id I mentioned earlier (to avoid duplicates and remove old indexes).

I am not sure what is meant by tokenizing.

Sam

Comment: I have used solr, not lucene directly. So not aware how merge policy works there. Tokenization means breaking the text into smaller pieces and indexing them. Because later small term queries are used for searching.